# How to get API answer with an API key using the requests package in Python

Tags: python, api, shell

How to get http request from API organized around REST,  JSON is returned by all API responses. All ressources have support for bulk fetches via "list" API methods

Here is what I have as documentation:

```
# With shell, you can just pass the correct header with each request
curl "https://www.api_url.com/api/dispute?page=1&limit=5"
  -H "Authorization: [api_key]"

# Query Parameters:
# page  1   The cursor used in the pagination (optional)
#limit  10  A limit on the number of dispute object to be returned, between 1 and 100 (optional).
```

I don't know how to interpret this in python and to pass api_key to extract the data from this object **dispute**

```
import requests
import json
response = requests.get("https://api_url.com/")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**curlconverter**](https://curlconverter.com/) tool to simplify the translation to Python code:

[image]

For the provided `curl` input:

```
curl "https://www.api_url.com/api/dispute?page=1&limit=5" \
  -H "Authorization: [api_key]"
```

Here is the result in Python. Note that I've changed `params` to a `dict` object, as it's easier to work with dictionaries in Python. It doesn't matter if the values for any of the query params are a type other than `str`, as they will simply be concatenated in the URL string when making the request.

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': '[api_key]',
}

params = {
    'page': 1,
    'limit': 5
}

response = requests.get('https://www.api_url.com/api/dispute',
                        headers=headers, params=params)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `-H` option in curl sets a header for the request.

For a request using `requests`, you can set extra headers by passing a keyword argument `headers`.

```py
import requests
import json

response = requests.get(
  "https://www.api_url.com/api/dispute",
  headers={"Authorization" : "<api_key_here>"}
)
```

You can also add your parameters easily if needed

```py
response = requests.get(
  "https://www.api_url.com/api/dispute",
  headers={"Authorization" : "<api_key_here>"},
  params={
    "page": 1,
    "limit":1
  }
)
```

If you want to make multiple requests, you can look into using a [`requests.Session`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session). [Session Tutorial](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects)

It will allow you to set the header centrally.

You can also use an [Auth Handler](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#authentication) to manage authentication.